# maximize the each pair of 3 function

Tags: python-3.x, loss-function, mean-square-error

I have 3 functions f1, f2, and f3 I want to know that what will be a lose function through which each pair of difference will be maximize e.g, max(f1-f2) max(f2-f3) max(f1-f3) these three things should be in one loss function

Comment: do you want a multi-objective or single-objective optimization?

Comment: It's unclear what are you looking for. What do you mean by maximizing a 3d-vector `(max1, max2, max3)`? Do you maximize an absolute values, or as you have written them? If two of max values are very big and the third one is zero, is it ok?